# How to call view from an other file than controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am creating a laravel 5.2 package, following are my files:

```
packages/
-Shreeji/
--Ring/
---composer.json
---src/
----Ring.php
----RingModel.php
----RingServiceProvider
----Views/
-----ringslist.blade.php
```

*composer.json*

```
{
 "name": "shreeji/ring",
 "description": "Simple",
 "license": "MIT",
 "authors": [
     {
         "name": "author",
         "email": "email@gmail.com"
     }
 ],
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
             "Shreeji\\Ring\\": "src/"
         }
     },
 "minimum-stability": "dev",
 "require": {
     "Illuminate/support": "~5"
 }
}
```

*Ring.php*

```
namespace Shreeji\Ring;

use Illuminate\Http\Response;

Class Ring {

function __construct() {

}

public function get_all()
{
    return view("ring::ringlist");
}

}
```

*RingServiceProvider.php*

```
namespace Shreeji\Ring;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

Class RingServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('ring', function($app){
        return new Ring;
    });
}

public function boot()
{
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/Views', 'ring');
}
}
```

*ringlist.blade.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <h1>Welcome</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

And in `app/Http/Controllers` I have created a test file like this:

*Ringcontroller.php*

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Shreeji\Ring\Ring;

class RingController extends Controller
{

 public function index()
 {
     $ring = New Ring();
     $ring->get_all();
 }
}
```

When I call the controller, browser keeps loading and crashed systematically. I don't know if I can use `view` outside any controller class like such.

Let me know if I did any mistake in calling `view` from *Ring.php* file.

Comment: Your controller needs to return something. Does it work if you `return $ring->get_all();`?

Comment: Problem is in _Ring.php_ file, while calling view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple issues I see:

1. You want to use views, but your package does not `require` the `illuminate/view` package. You need to update your `composer.json` file to require `"illuminate/view": "~5"`.
2. The `view()` function is a helper method included at `Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php`. Unless you want to depend on the entire Laravel framework just for this function, you will need to create your own `view()` function. The code is below, where you put it is up to you.

   ```
   if (! function_exists('view')) {
       /**
        * Get the evaluated view contents for the given view.
        *
        * @param  string  $view
        * @param  array   $data
        * @param  array   $mergeData
        * @return \Illuminate\View\View|\Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory
        */
       function view($view = null, $data = [], $mergeData = [])
       {
           $factory = app(ViewFactory::class);

           if (func_num_args() === 0) {
               return $factory;
           }

           return $factory->make($view, $data, $mergeData);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Once you get the view stuff working, you can make views all day long, but if you don't `return` anything from your controller, you're not going to see anything. Make sure you return something from your controller methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use somethin like view composer [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views)

In your RingServiceProvider register a composer

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory as ViewFactory;
public function boot(ViewFactory $view)
{
    $view->composer('*', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\SomeComposer');
}
```

And in `App\Http\ViewComposers\SomeComposer`

```
    use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('count', '1');
    }
```

Play around with it, basically I am using it share $variables on particular views but maybe this can help you achieve what you want.

Or u can just `use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;` to load your view that you need!